# php redis hscan return empty results

Tags: php, redis

I have problem with `hscan` command in php.

When i run command in `redis-cli` everything works well.

`hscan some:key 0 match *word*`

But in php i've got empty result.

```php
<?php

$it = null;

$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);

$results = $redis->hscan('products:search2', $it, '*word*');

var_dump($results);
```

I use `phpredis` php extension.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i've got this. I just **forget to select database** to 1,
because my data is on database 1.
Redis as a default look in database 0.

The answer is:

```php
<?php

$redis->select(1);
```